# Is complexity of the following two recurrances same?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

I have two recurrance relations as:

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + c       // complexity O(logn)

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c      // is the complexity O(logn)????
```

c is a constant in both case i.e. we are doing constant work in the merge part of recurrance.

First recurrance is of Binary Search where we are continuously discarding one half of array.

Let say second recurrance finds the max element from an array that is unsorted and we are dividing the array in two parts in each step, then comparing the result of each part to give a single max value.

In the first case we are not traversing the whole array. In the second we are traversing the whole. Now if i build a recursion tree for both i would get a complexity of O(logn) as the height of both the trees are same. If i am wrong please correct me. It is a confusion in my mind, so please help me clear it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)

Comment: case for master theorem is that when the merging function is in terms of n. In my case it is constant, so how is master theorem applicable??

Comment: @Dukeling Its case 1 and not case 2, kindly correct yourself.

Comment: @JotWaraich From what I understand its a very simple case of Master's Theorem. Do clear your basics dude.

Comment: Yes @Sumeet Singh figured it out after asking the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's *not* the same complexity. The second one would be something like `O(n)`

A simple way to see this is to fix `c = 0` and `T(1) = a` (whare `a` is a constant).

Then:

```
T(2) = 2T(1) = 2a
T(4) = 2T(2) = 4a
T(8) = 2T(4) = 8a
...
T(n) = n*a
```

You can see a linear complexity.

Comment: if we build it, it will point to logn complexity. what about that??

Comment: Well, you can do the same reasonning: `T(1) = a`, `T(2) = T(1)+c = a+c`, `T(4) = T(2)+c = a+2c`, `T(8) = T(4)+c = a+3c`, ... So `T(2^n) = a+nc ~ nc`, and `T(n) = O(log_2(n))`

Comment: Actually, there are 2 steps when you solve using recursion tree: building the tree, and searching in it. Building it costs `O(n*log(n))`, which is even worse than linear. But once the tree is built, every time you can search on it in `O(log(n))`. So it all depends on how any times you need to search the result.